# excel test if proper substring

Tags: excel, text, substring

Let's say I have A1 contain text ABC, and B1 contains BC. How do I test if B1 contains a proper subset of A1? So, BC being a proper subset of ABC, answer should be true, but DE not being a proper subset of ABC, answer should be false.

Comment: @findwindow your comments are quite rude, I am trying to find an answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try that

```
=ISNUMBER(FIND(B1;A1))
```

[image]

Comment: Semicolon should be replaced by comma, and if A1 contains ABC and B1 contains D, still =ISNUMBER(FIND(B1;A1)) yields TRUE

Comment: Semicolon is just the delimiter in my language setting and as you did not provide any example formula I could not infer your locale ...

Comment: Regarding the "error": see my screenshot. Maybe you should either check it again or rephrase your question as there is obviously a difference between what you want and how we interpret your question

Answer (score 0):

This does the job:

```
=IF(ISERR(SEARCH(B1,A1)),"false", "true")
```

It's slightly contrived but first uses the SEARCH method to find the string which returns either the starting position if found (e.g. 2) or an error if not.

The IsErr function then returns true if the string was not found, or false if it was (the inverse of the required behaviour).

Finally the If function effectively reverses the boolean values, returning false if there was an error (string not found) or true if it was.

Comment: if A1 contains ABC and B1 contains D, still =IF(ISERR(SEARCH(B1,A1)),"false", "true") yields true